# Dold-Kan preserves weak equivalences and fibrations

Tags: reference-request, simplicial-stuff, chain-complexes

It's well known that [Dold-Kan correspondence](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Dold-Kan+correspondence) is an isomorphism between simplicial vector spaces and non-negative chain complexes of vector spaces. Moreover, weak equivalences and fibrations are preserved.

Could anyone point a reference to not only the statement but also an explicit proof (that preserves weak equivalences and fibrations)? If the proof is simple or straightforward, a hint is appreciated.

Comment: All you ask about is proved in the link you provide or in the references therein.

Comment: @FernandoMuro Thanks, could you please be more specific? What I found is "this is discussed for instance in section 4.1 of SchwedeShipley". I have a look at SchwedeShipley, and find the statement without proof or reference, that is why I said "not only the statement but also an explicit proof".

Comment: Ma Ming, you're right, the proof is not there. Anyway, if you know how the functors are defined, then you'll see that the proof is trivial.

Comment: The proof is indeed trivial.  There is a subtlety that can trip the unwary: fibrations in "non-negative chain complexes" are not necessarily fibrations in "unbounded chain complexes".  In this  context, fibrations in non-negative chain complexes are $f:A_\bullet\to B_\bullet$ which are surjective for $\bullet\geq 1$ (but necessarily for $\bullet=0$).